# Unexpected namespace prefix "android" found for tag TextView in android eclipse

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http:/schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin)"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizomtal_margin"
tools:context=".AnaEkranActivity" >


<TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Screen" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

I am having 2 errors.

```
Suspicious namespace: should start with http://
```

at first line.

Other is:

```
Unexpected namespace prefix "android" found for tag TextView
```

at `android:text` line.

What is the reason? It is well formatted

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

Instead of:

```
xmlns:android="http:/schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

you forgot one `/` in your url.

The 2nd error you get seems to be just aftermath of the first error.